# How do I connect my server to a WEP encrypted wireless network?

Tags: 10.04, server, wireless

I've recently started working with Ubuntu Server 10.04, but I'm having a problem while connecting to WEP-encrypted Wifi.

I've tried the following:

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
sudo dhclient -r wlan0  
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up  
sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid "<essid>"
sudo iwconfig wlan0 key <hex key>
```

Then, I tried to connect to the Wifi by running `sudo dhclient wlan0`, however, I keep getting the same error- **No DHCPOFFERS received.**

Am I doing this the right way, or is there something I'm forgetting?

`sudo ifconfig` yields:

```
wlan0 Link encap: Ethernet HWAaddr 00:1f:1f:3b:3c:3e  
UP BROADCAST MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1  
RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0  
TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0  
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000  
X bytes:0 (0.0B) TX Bytes:0 (0.0B)
```

While  `sudo iwconfig` yields:

```
wlan0 IEEE 802.11bg ESSID:"GlobalNetwork"  
Mode:Managed Access Point: Not-Associated Tx-Power:8 dBm  
Retry long limit:7 RTS thr:off Fragment thr:off  
Encryption key:my-hex-key  
Power Management:off
```

I'm trying to connect with a Ralink RT2561 that shows up with `lshw -C network`.

Any help you can give me is much appreciated, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try checking if the driver for the wlan is up-to-date? You could hook up a lan cable until all the updates and drivers are gotten and installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are receiving ( "No DHCPOFFERS received" ) seems to suggest that there is no DHCP server in your network. So I do not think is a WEP problem...

I assume that your are trying to connect to a "normal" router ( so you do not have separate DHCP server, firewalls or other stuff between your server and the router ).

1. disable wep and try to connect again to the network. If this works, probably there was an error in the WEP password you entered.
2. try to connect to the network by cable. This way you can check if through ethernet the DHCP works and an IP address is given to your server. If you receive an IP address the problem could be wireless card drivers or misconfiguration.
3. check DHCP setting for the router. Maybe something is messed up on the router side, access it's configuration page and try to understand if settings are correct. You can also try to connect to the wifi connection through another computer ( just to be sure that the problem is the server! )
4. config your server to use a static IP address ( this way you won't be using DHCP ):
   http://usefulubuntu.blogspot.com/2009/01/create-static-ip-from-command-line.html
   Please remember to check the IP address you will insert ( could be taken by someone else in the network ) and be sure to put the correct gateway address!

Comment: Wow... nice gravedig. Thanks, but I just scrapped Ubuntu Server and went to Desktop.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the #1 Key, NOT the Passphrase.  The key shows "Default" and cannot be changed, but when I entered the key instead of the passphrase - BOOM - I was, and am connected.

Comment: Please edit your answer to make this into more documentation and less comments. Currently it is rather difficult to understand.